# How can I divide the Eigen::matrix by Eigen::vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen, eigen3

following is my code.

```
    Eigen::Matrix3d first_rotation = firstPoint.q.matrix();
    Eigen::Vector3d first_trans= firstPoint.t;
    for(auto &iter:in_points )
    {
                
                iter.second.t= first_rotation / (iter.second.t-first_trans).array();
    }
```

However,the vscode says"no operator / matches the operands" for division."
How can I division a matrix by a vector?

In Matlab, the line was `t2 = R1 \ (R2 - t1);`

Comment: What kind of result would you expect from dividing a matrix by a vector?

Comment: If you could write the element-wise loop version of what you want, it should be easy enough to formulate the Eigen version.

Comment: @mfnx it should return a vector3d. But it says -- Eigen::Matrix3d first_rotation / Eigen::Vector3d (iter.second.t - first_trans).array() , which is not allowed. Where am i wrong?

Comment: @Homer512 Could Eigen allow that Eigen:: Matrix3d / Eigen::Vector3d . Or how to use Eigen's division.

Comment: You still did not clarify what result you expect (i.e., what should be the entries of the resulting vector). Either give a "manual" definition (how would you implement it as a loop), or an implicit definition (give an equation that would only be true for the result vector).

Comment: @AdamPengC If you want a vector result, it sounds like you want to solve a linear equation system. Is that it? Did you see a formula like ```y = A^-1 * x``` or Matlab's ```y = A \ x``` syntax and think this was division?

Comment: @Homer512 Yeah, in my matlab, the sentence is “ t2 = R1 \ (R2 - t1);”. And if there a way can use" \ " in Eigen?

Comment: You might want to check out Eigen docs on solving linear systems (that is what \ in Matlab does).

Comment: In linear algebra, there is no meaningful operation defined as the quotient of a matrix by a vector because in general, a matrix does not factor as the outer product of two vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab defined the `/` and `\` operators, when applied to matrices, as solving linear equation systems, as you can read up on in their [operator documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/matlab-operators-and-special-characters.html). In particular

> `x = A\B` solves the system of linear equations `A*x = B`

Eigen doesn't do this. And I don't think most other languages or libraries do it either. The main point is that there are multiple ways to decompose a matrix for solving. Each with their own pros and cons. You can read up on it in [their documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html).

In your case, you can save time by reusing the decomposition multiple times. Something like this:

```
Eigen::PartialPivLU<Eigen::Matrix3d> first_rotation =
      firstPoint.q.matrix().partialPivLu();
for(auto &iter: in_points)
    iter.second.t = first_rotation.solve(
          (iter.second.t-first_trans).eval());
```

Note: I picked LU over e.g. householderQr because [that is what Matlab does for general square matrices](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96919-how-does-the-backslash-operator-work-when-a-is-full). If you know more about your input matrix, e.g. that it is symmetrical, or not invertible, try something else.

Note 2: I'm not sure it is necessary in this case but I added a call to `eval` so that the left side of the assignment is not an alias of anything on the right side. With dynamically sized vectors, this would introduce extra memory allocations but here it is fine.

Comment: Hi @Homer512, I appreciate your answer. I will try this way. Could get the rotation by "first_rotation.slove(iter.rotation)", like the way " rotationResult= rotationFirst/rotationIter",in matlab?

Comment: @AdamPengC Well, ```first_rotation.partialPivLu().solve(...)``` to be exact but yes, that is the equivalent. I just separated it because you don't need to redo the LU decomposition for every point.